# mysql_fetch_row Shows Only the First record

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
                       $dabs = mysql_select_db('data180', $con);

                        /*Query database for data  */

                        $res=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clients');
                        $array = mysql_fetch_row($res);
                    print_r($array);
```

**Updating my Question:**

I  used

```
            while($array=mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            print_r($array);
            }
```

and  it works fine but  there is something wrong with the result. This is part of the print_r($array) result:

Array ( [0] => 2 [Client] => 2 [1] => 222 [Redmine Issue #] => 222 [2] => 0 [Legacy Data Conversion Required?] => 0 [3] => 2014-12-01 [Contract Date] => 2014-12-01 [4] => #C0C0C0 [SSO Implemented] => #C0C0C0 [5] => #C0C0C0 [Legacy Data Converted] => #C0C0C0 [6] => #C0C0C0 [Moved to Production(Date)] => #C0C0C0 [7] => #0000FF [First Workload Initiated] => #0000FF [8] => #0000FF [First Evaluation Completed] => #0000FF ) Array ( [0] => 3 [Client] => 3

you can see that each field is repeated 2 times, once with a numeric key and once with key name.

Comment: Why are you using a deprecated API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call mysql_fetch_array function inside while loop

```
 while($array=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
        print_r($array);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`.

> **mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )**
>
> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on
>   how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get
>   an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC,
>   you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), [by]
>   using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row()
>   works).
>
> **mysql_fetch_row ( resource $result )**
>
> Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched
>   row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated
>   with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array.
>   Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

Alos refer Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score -1):

use mysql_fetch_array. 
or mysql_fetch_assoc

The mysql_fetch_row is used to fetch only one row

Comment: That answer is completely wrong. The only difference is that `mysql_fetch_row` uses numeric indexes for columns instead of both (`mysql_fetch_array`) or string indexes (`mysql_fetch_assoc`).